# Error initializing sockets: port=6000. Address already in use

Tags: linux

I lunched a simulator program which developed on C++ in my Ubuntu 11 when i want kill this process from process list of Linux and want to run it again, i faced to this error:

> ```
> Error initializing sockets: port=6000. Address already in use
> ```

I used lsof command to find PID of process:

> ```
> saman@jack:~$ lsof -i:6000
> COMMAND    PID  USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
> rcssserve 8764 saman    3u  IPv4  81762      0t0  UDP *:x11
> ```

after that i tried to kill PID of 8764. but still it has error.
How can i fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem you are having is that the socket if it is not shutdown correctly then it is still reserved and waiting for a timeout to be closed by the kernel.

Try doing a `netstat -nutap` and see if there's a line like this:

```
tcp        0      0 AAA.AAA.AAA.AAA:6000     XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:YYYY       TIME_WAIT   -
```

if that's the case you just have to wait until the kernel drops it (30 secs approx) until you can open the socket at 6000 without conflict

Comment: udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:6000            0.0.0.0:*                           3543/rcssserver , how ever kernel doesnt dropt it.

Comment: rcsserver is the simulator you are running? Cause that process is in possession of the socket, you should kill it. It is not an incorrectly closed socket

Comment: yes rcssserver is a the simulator. yes you are right. it works.

Answer (score 0):

It would seem that port 6000 is used by the X windowing system (the GUI part of linux) and is probably just restarted when you kill the process...  either you'll need run the simulation without X-windows running, or you tweak the code to use a different port..